# Android theme is not changing

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I made a splash screen using two styles first is the default style without 'windowBackground' and the second is splash screen style with 'windowBackground'. The problem is that when I am changing style using getApplication().setTheme in the MainActivity using the code below:

```
@Override
protected final void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // this line of code is not changing theme
    getApplication().setTheme(R.style.Theme_Defaults);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

The splash screen is not disappearing ('windowBackground' is not removed from 'SpScreen' style)

**Manifest:**

```
 <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/SpScreen"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:extractNativeLibs="false"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
```

**Theme.xml:**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Defaults" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorInt</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorInt</item>
    <item name="android:supportsPerformanceGameMode" tools:ignore="NewApi">true</item>
    <item name="android:forceHasOverlappingRendering" tools:ignore="NewApi">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
    <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
    <item name="android:allowGameFpsOverride" tools:ignore="NewApi">true</item>
    <item name="android:largeHeap">true</item>
    <item name="android:allowGameAngleDriver" tools:ignore="NewApi">true</item>
</style>

<style name="SpScreen" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorInt</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorInt</item>
    <item name="android:supportsPerformanceGameMode" tools:ignore="NewApi">true</item>
    <item name="android:forceHasOverlappingRendering" tools:ignore="NewApi">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
    <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
    <item name="android:allowGameFpsOverride" tools:ignore="NewApi">true</item>
    <item name="android:largeHeap">true</item>
    <item name="android:allowGameAngleDriver" tools:ignore="NewApi">true</item>
    
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/backgroud_splashscreen</item>
</style>
```

The only difference between the styles is:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/backgroud_splashscreen</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
getApplication().setTheme(R.style.Theme_Defaults);
```

Try using:

```
getLayoutInflater().getContext().setTheme(R.style.Theme_Defaults);
```

This should work.